# A word for the effect that brightness has on someone who needs to sneeze

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Whenever someone has to sneeze my family tells them to look at a bright light. This makes most people sneeze.

Recently someone told us that there is a special word or phrase for this.

Is this so? Does anyone know the word?

Comment: how to google this: https://www.google.ca/search?q=sneeze+bright+light -> first hit is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photic_sneeze_reflex.  I hope that gives you a useful idea to improve your search skills.

Comment: Thanks, I do have trouble finding things with google! How exactly do the + work?

Comment: Spaces in a text field turn into `+`es in the form-submission URL.  The actual search string is [`sneeze bright light`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sneeze+bright+light) (with no quotes or punctuation or anything).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Photoptarmosis**

From [wikipedia: Photic sneeze reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photic_sneeze_reflex)

> The photic sneeze reflex (also known as photoptarmosis, Autosomal
>   Dominant Compelling Helio-Ophthalmic Outburst Syndrome (ACHOO) and
>   colloquially sun sneezing) is a condition that causes variable
>   difficulty to control sneezing in response to numerous stimuli, such
>   as looking at bright lights or periocular (surrounding the eyeball)
>   injection. The condition affects 18-35% of the population, but its
>   exact mechanism of action is not well understood.

Comment: This answer gives the key information (so, +1), but highlights the wrong term: **photic sneeze reflex** is far more widely used and understood than *photoptarmosis*.

Comment: I would have highlighted that instead, but the OP requested a single word.